# Python ignore error in multiprocessing pool map

Tags: python, exception, multiprocessing, pool

In main program I have:

```
def main_func:
    ...
    #main function
    pool= Pool(processes=10)
    res = pool.map(function_b,verylonglist)
    ...
```

and function_b

```
def function_b:
   try:
      #dosomething
   except:
      pass
```

I'm just new to python so I want to ask  how can handle the exception. I want the process ignore all mapping that raise error and collect the correct one. As in my code, the process will say some errors and then running non stop again and again at that point. Thank you.

Comment: Are you saying you want to retry the calls that fail, or just ignore them?

Comment: I want to ignore them. But the system keep retry and stuck at that point

Comment: In your except block just return some value that you can later recognise as a value that should be ignored.

Comment: Thank Alex, I will try that.